# Using "on duplicate key" with multiple duplicate condition

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

I have table contains questions data. Also every question has test id, document id (dokuman_id), order (sira) and video data. I want to create a query that insert new row if there isn't a row has same test id, document id and order; else just update video field.

[image]

I know I could use ON DUPLICATE KEY if I want to do it with id(primart_key) column. But I need to control 3 duplicate column conditions as optimum as possible.

Comment: So create a combined unique index over all three columns …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create index on `test_id , dokuman_id , sira`

```
INSERT INTO table (test_id , dokuman_id , sira , video) 
VALUES(:test_id , :dokuman_id , :sira , :video) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE video = :video
```

Comment: Do I have to delete primary key before this?

Comment: no you don't have to delete the primary key , you just create another index

Comment: Ok thank you mate. But I just don't understand how db decides key for **on duplicate key**. There can be many keys

Comment: @nskmr The engine checks **every** unique key (including the primary key) for duplicates.